# How to make redirect in htaccess except for one folder and its directories and files inside and one path for cms Joomla

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, joomla, joomla3.6

How to perform redirection in .htaccess file except for one folder and its directories and files inside and one path

I would like to perform the redirect as follows
from domain

```
www.olddomain.org
www.olddomain.org/^ (any path)
to the domain:
www.newdomain.org
www.newdomain.org/^ (any path)
```

```
BUT except for
www.olddomain.org/administrator/test/test1/test2
www.olddomain.org/administrator/ (any path)
AND
www.olddomain.org/test-article
```

I would like to add that I want to make these redirects for the Joomla 3 CMS system

I try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.pl
#redirect them to new-example
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/administrator/^
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/testarticle
RewriteRule (.*) https://newdomain.pl/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/administrator.*/$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.newdomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

But it doesn't work the way I want

Comment: You might try [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch 301 ^/((?!administrator).*)$ http://newdomain.org/$1
```

Comment: This works, but is a part of my question ;) But good answer anyway:)

Comment: The next problem is redirecting all pages to new domain with path but except one from old domain. Look up to post description and section started with: "BUT except for".